# How can I make ActionBarDrawerToggle more prominent?

Tags: android-layout, android

Following Android guidelines I have added `ActionBarDrawerToggle` which brings up a `DrawerLayout`.

This is fine but I can't help feeling my users will have a hard time noticing it since it's so tiny.

Before that I had several tabs in the `ActionBar` but there were too many `tabs` so I did replace them with the `DrawerLayout` as they say to do when you have more than 3 `tabs`.

However, are there any techniques to make the `Drawer Toggle` more prominent without breaking up the Android Design Guidelines. Are there any examples to that?

Answer (score 3):

As detailed in the [Navigation Drawer Interaction Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction):

> **Introduce the user to the drawer at first use**
>
> Upon first launch of your app, introduce the user to the navigation drawer by automatically opening it. This ensures that users know about the navigation drawer and prompts them to learn about the structure of your app by exploring its content. Continue showing the drawer upon subsequent launches until the user actively expands the navigation drawer manually. Once you know that the user understands how to open the drawer, launch the app with the navigation drawer closed.

This ensures that users understand that the Navigation Drawer exists and that they notice the drawer toggle animating as they close/open the drawer.

Comment: How to konw "user actively expands the navigation drawer manually"

Comment: Ian, I'm wondering, is this still up-to-date? The guidelines don't contain that part anymore, but I know that there are still a whole lot of users that have never used the navigation drawer for some reason.

Comment: @0101100101 - I'd encourage you to look over the [navigation patterns section](https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns) - one of the suggested reasons to use [tabs](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html) or [bottom navigation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html) is specifically **Promoting awareness of alternate views** - bottom navigation is probably the most appropriate if you have <=5 equally important top level screens.